# Extend background color to fill window yet keep elements in place

Tags: html, css

http://69.143.137.155/csa-consulting/index.php

I am trying to extend the grey menu bar and the blue background to fill the window (whatever the size) yet keep the content centered at a fixed size. Been working on getting this for a while and cannot seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: Safari/Chrome, FF, Opera, IE7+

Answer (score 0):

Use a background image on the `<body>`.

```
.body {
    background:#F2F4EE url(menu-bar.jpg) TOP CENTER REPEAT-X;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because I'd like to make a footer with the same attributes (centered content, repeating background)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the width style to your `nav` class. Like so

```
.nav
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following declarations from `#container`:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1024px;
```

Add the following declaration to `body`:

```
margin: 0;
```

Comment: ...? Then my content wont be centered as it needs to be, and part of the page is supposed to have the specific width (1024). The extended background is to make the page look good at higher resolutions.

Comment: I tried it on Chrome and it is centered. Maybe you have an issue with another browser. You can add the `width: 1024px;` declaration to the inner element if you want.